# JOIN CONDICIONADO SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta sql server:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) as begins, al.id_almacen, u.group_identifier,  
        e.cargo, 
        CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
            DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) 
        ELSE 
            0
        END
        as horas,
 CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
            DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) 
        ELSE 
            0
        END
        as horas,
        CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
            md.meta_diaria
        ELSE 
            0
        END
        AS meta_diaria,  
        c.semana_bono, 
        CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
            (ROUND(md.meta_diaria, 2) / SUM( CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), al.id_almacen) ) * ( DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) )   
        ELSE 
            0
        END as meta,
        SUM( CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), al.id_almacen) AS total_horas_turno_dia,  
        ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN e.cargo = 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN md.meta_diaria END) OVER(PARTITION BY semana_bono, al.id_almacen), 2) as meta_semanal_tienda 

    FROM usuarios as u 
        INNER JOIN planificacion as p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
        INNER JOIN turnos as t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
        INNER JOIN empleado as e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '') = u.identifier 
        LEFT JOIN almacen as al ON ( al.cod_almacen = u.group_identifier) 

    WHERE P.begins = 20160701   
        AND  al.cod_almacen = '101'  
        AND u.enabled = 1 

    ORDER BY begins, group_identifier ASC;
```

que retorna:

```
id_calendario   id_almacen  cod_almacen         cargo
   20190617         32          110       VENDEDOR DE TEMPORADA
   20190617         32          110       VENDEDOR FULL TIME 2
   20190617         32          110       VENDEDOR FULLTIME 1
   20190617         32          110       JEFE(A) DE TIENDA
```

Dejando por fuera otros cargos porque no cumplen con la condición

```
 LEFT JOIN almacen as al ON ( al.cod_almacen = u.group_identifier)
```

Otros registros son obtenidos con :

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) as begins, al.id_almacen, u.group_identifier,  
        e.cargo, 
        CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
            DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) 
        ELSE 
            0
        END
        as horas 
    FROM usuarios as u 
        INNER JOIN planificacion as p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
        INNER JOIN turnos as t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
        INNER JOIN empleado as e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '') = u.identifier 
       LEFT JOIN almacen as al ON ( al.cod_almacen = e.cod_almacen_ingreso)
 WHERE P.begins = 20160701   
        AND  al.cod_almacen = '101'  
        AND u.enabled = 1 

    ORDER BY begins, group_identifier ASC;
```

AL CAMBIAR LA CONDICION:

```
LEFT JOIN almacen as al ON ( al.cod_almacen = u.group_identifier)
```

POR

```
LEFT JOIN almacen as al ON ( al.cod_almacen = e.cod_almacen_ingreso)
```

Como hago para obtener la totalidad de los registros que cumplen con una o ambas condiciones en el mismo select?

Intenté con UNION y me devuelve varios valores repetidos

Intenté con ( al.cod_almacen = u.group_identifier) OR ( al.cod_almacen = e.cod_almacen_ingreso)  pero no calculas los campos que son partición de almacen

Comment: No entiendo que queres hacer. Debe ser reemplazada por que cosa?

Comment: Y si realizas otro JOIN sobre la misma tabla de nuevo pero con diferente alias? no te seriviria eso

Comment: tiene que cumplir una condicion u otra? o las dos? o sea.. sabias que podes usar and, or y otras cosas como clausula del join?

Comment: @gbianchi Una u otra

Comment: @Edgar Vazquez  lo intenté y me da error en los campos que son calculados

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: @Edgar Vazquez no los calcula, los deja NULL

Comment: ok tratare de ponerte la respuesta lo checas y seguimos comentando ahi.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este y observamos los detalles que nos pudieran salir.
Saludos

```
   SELECT SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) as begins, COALESCE(al.id_almacen,al2.id_almacen), u.group_identifier,  
            e.cargo, 
            CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
                DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) 
            ELSE 
                0
            END
            as horas,
     CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
                DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) 
            ELSE 
                0
            END
            as horas,
            CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
                md.meta_diaria
            ELSE 
                0
            END
            AS meta_diaria,  
            c.semana_bono, 
            CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
                (ROUND(md.meta_diaria, 2) / SUM( CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), al.id_almacen) ) * ( DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) )   
            ELSE 
                0
            END as meta,
            SUM( CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), COALESCE(al.id_almacen,al2.id_almacen)) AS total_horas_turno_dia,  
            ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN e.cargo = 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN md.meta_diaria END) OVER(PARTITION BY semana_bono, COALESCE(al.id_almacen,al2.id_almacen)), 2) as meta_semanal_tienda 

        FROM usuarios as u 
            INNER JOIN planificacion as p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
            INNER JOIN turnos as t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
            INNER JOIN empleado as e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '') = u.identifier 
            LEFT JOIN almacen as al ON ( al.cod_almacen = u.group_identifier) 
            LEFT JOIN almacen as al2 ON ( al2.cod_almacen = e.cod_almacen_ingreso)

        WHERE P.begins = 20160701   
            AND  al.cod_almacen = '101'  
            AND u.enabled = 1 

        ORDER BY begins, group_identifier ASC;
```

Los siguientes campos a que tabla le pertenecen ?

> (hour, start_hour, end_hour)

Comment: no es mejor una sola tabla almacen y poner como condicion de join al.cod_almacen = u.group_identifier OR al2.cod_almacen = e.cod_almacen_ingreso????

Comment: @Edgar Vazquez los campos (hour, start_hour, end_hour) son de la tabla turnos.  Ejecuté el ejemplo y no retorna nada

Comment: Con cual query es con la que me dices que si te trajo pero te dejo algunos en null? me lo podrias enseñar

Comment: @Edgar Vazquez Cuando hago el UNION de los select que coloqué en la redacción de la pregunta.  Pero me están cambiando las pautas, cerraré ésta consulta para publicar otra duda.  Gracias

Comment: Claro, si puedo ayudarte en la otra con gusto lo hare saludos